# marquee type message on sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

How do I add a marquee type message on sharepoint online? (moving message).

I tried adding below code on a content editor page.

```
<FONT face="Verdana" color=#ff0000 size=2>
  <P align=center>
    <MARQUEE scrollDelay=95 width=500 height=16>
      <DIV align=left>Note: Replace this sample text with any message applicable to your particular situation.</DIV>
    </MARQUEE>
  </P>
</FONT>
```

but when I save and close the page. its not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In order for DIV to work inside MARQUEE, you need to use this style for the DIV.

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773212/can-i-put-divs-inside-marquee-element)